# How to use DataTables (jQuery) with Twig in Symfony?

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables, twig

I am trying to use the jQuery DataTables plugin in my Symfony project.

The following code works:

```
<table width="100%" id="table_id">

                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                                <td>$170,750</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                                <td>$86,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                <td>$320,800</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                                <td>$170,750</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                                <td>$86,000</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

But I have a problem with the following code generated with a loop in Twig:

```
            <table width="100%" id="table_id">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>

                <tbody>
                    {% for courrier in listCourrier %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ courrier.DateRegister().Creation()|date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ courrier.User().Username() }}</td>
                        <tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The table appears with the good values but I do not have the sorting arrows. It seems to be a problem with jQuery and Twig. I would prefer not to use a Bundle to do that (I tried some bundles but it was difficult to use it to do what I want). So, if you have any idea to simply include the DataTables jQuery plugin, I would be grateful.

Comment: If you copy the source of your table is it valid HTML? I'm only asking because it all looks good from here. I guess the other question is whether or not you've included the JS and CSS?

Comment: The JS and CSS files are well included because when I replace the table generated by Twig by the equivalent HTLM above, it works perfectly. I think the code from Twig is valid (the Datatables without arrows to sort appears) but there is an apparent problem with Twig and jQuery.

Comment: Have you looked at KnpPaginatorBundle at all?

Comment: It seems to be very interesting. I found a solution to my problem by using Ajax with DataTables but I will look at this bundle! Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery data-table like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [];
            data.push(
                [1,"Sasha","Brenna","0800 1111"],
                [2,"Sage","Mia","(01012) 405872"],
                [3,"Chelsea","Allistair","076 0578 0265"],
                [4,"Uta","Savannah","070 1247 5884"],
                [5,"Remedios","Berk","0995 181 0007"]
            );

            $('#data_table').DataTable( {
                data: data,
            });
        });
});

<table id="data_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Emp Code</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <!-- Dynamic Body -->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/21/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to use the variables sent from my controller to my Twig file. You used data.push() but do you know an other function to get the variables I sent from my controller so as to generate the cells of my table?

Comment: You can change that data source from your ajax data source. Its just an example

Comment: Or you can use server side datatable in which you can directly use controller data  in it